# qgis to local postgis connection - fails

Tags: postgis, qgis, postgresql

It seems pretty clear I cannot connect to a local postgresql installation out of QGIS. This is my first experience with PostGIS. 
I am using PostgreSQL 9.0 on a win7 machine. I can see the successful installation of Postgresql and the postgis database in both PGAdmin and NaviCat. I have added a user account in PGAdmin which is not a superuser (meaning I believe I have dealt with the issues discussed at http://pgsnake.blogspot.com/2010/07/postgresql-passwords-and-installers.html).

Has something changed on QGIS 1.7?

After I choose to Add Postgis Layer, I specify a new connection which resembles my configuration and is consistent with http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/34-working-with-your-postgis-layers-using-quantum-gis-qgis.html and the Linfinity blog. I have toggled SSL mode after reading http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Postgis-SSL-connection-td2037146.html.

The failure in the test connection leads to "ERROR:service file "/etc/pg_service.conf" not found".

Has anyone got some more positive experience with PostgreSQL, QGIS and Win7?

Comment: darn! i had the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The service parameter in the QGIS/PostGIS dialog should be empty. 
And I spent a bit of time killing the user account "postgres" in windows and removing the names of the databases which are created in the windows registry. 
After that I could repeatedly fail the dialog by having something in the service parameter of the QGIS Postgis connection dialog.

Comment: GIS SE wants me to wait a few hours till I can do this...