# Connect to PostgreSQL localhost in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am fairly new to actively work with databases. I wanted to try out some stuff on my home computer where I have installed pgAdmin and PostgreSQL previously. I can connect to my localhost in pgAdmin but I can't do the same in QGIS. I just get an error message saying:

```
"Connection failed -  Check settings and try again"
```

I am new in this game and don't really know where to look for solutions. My database connection info is standard settings:

```
Name: postgres
Host:Localhost
Port:5432
Database:test
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Chances are you are setting the `service` parameter, which has to be left empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll add an answer with a screenshot, as it will be easier to look at for reference.

Here is an example with the absolute minimum you would have to enter.
It would connect to a database called *twitter*, and I would name that connection twitterDB. Note that it *does not matter* how you name the connection; this is just a name you give to your connection so you can refer to it later on (see last screenshot).

[image]

And here a screenshot of the actual database I am connecting to:

[image]

In QGIS your connection would show up like this:

[image]

Hit the *Connect* button, and if it worked, the *Schema* area will be populated, where you can then navigate to your tables.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you post and prtscreen! I think I had my settings in properly, but I will try again. Can reply with a printscreen of my settings.
Wonder if it can have something to do with the installation of QGIS/postgres

Answer (score 4):

`Name` is the name of the database connection, you have to enter `username` and `password` below as well. Host should be `localhost`, not Localhost.

You might need Postgis as well, see

[How to fix "Connection failed - Check settings and try again" when connecting to PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69569/how-to-fix-connection-failed-check-settings-and-try-again-when-connecting-to)

[How to connect to Postgres with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/38937/how-to-connect-to-postgres-with-qgis)

[qgis to local postgis connection - fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12004/qgis-to-local-postgis-connection-fails)

for further advice.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and attached links, I realize that my questions is really generalized and not very specified, I will go through the links and try to sort it out"