# Searching/Filtering capability in GIS?

Tags: filter, search

I'm a database administrator who's working with a new client who'd like to use a "search" or "filter" application with GIS. For example, he would like to search within his area of properties that are over 30 acres, have this elevation, etc.

Is there a way to search in that system or to create a search/filter system?

Answer (score 1):

You could surely use a GIS for that, but since you are coming from a database background I would suggest you look into PostgreSQL with a [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) extension. That would enable you to use all of the usual SQL plus a good amount of functions that are solely related to spatial data. Depending on how complex your client's queries would be that would surely be a better option than any "real" GIS. Since you have a good understanding of databases it would also most likely be the easiest for you to set up for your client.

Would your client desire to also visualize the results then you could hook up PostgreSQL to a GIS software, like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/). QGIS is open source, you can download it for free, and it is very easy to set up a connection to PostgreSQL. I actually showed how to do that in an [earlier post today](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133409/connect-to-postgres-localhost-in-qgis/133434#133434).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative light weight option would be to use SQLite/spatiallite and QGIS as @BritishSteel mentioned as the client viewer.

[QGIS Query Builder](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html)